# How can I get users to auto join a conference at login on my xmpp server?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I want to setup a local XMPP server, and I want each user to automatically to enter an important conference when they login, or at least get sent an invitations, but I can't figure out how.

Can I do this through the settings in ejabberd, or would this be a function in a different server?

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled entirely by the client.  [The server can control which rooms are able to be auto-joined, with the `autojoin` attribute of the conference `element` element](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html#format-conference), but it's up to the XMPP client to actually do so.

Note that the default value for the `autojoin` attribute is false, but once you set that to `true` on the server, its entirely up to whatever client you're using to support auto-joining.

Comment: How i can config this. I can't find this on ejabberd.cfg, ejabberd admin or my xmpp client conference config.

Comment: This depends on the client, you need to check if it has the option to add a chatroom to bookmark when you join it.